# Local port forwarding from Mac to Linux for Django server

Tags: linux, django, macos, ssh, portforwarding

I have a Django server that runs on Linux that can be accessed at `localhost:8000`. My local machine runs on Mac OS X and I was able to start the server on the remote Linux machine by ssh-ing into the Linux machine and then running the command to start the server (in my case, it starts with `docker-compose up` since the server runs inside a docker container).

In my shell, I can see the server is running on the Linux machine. I now want to see if I can access that Django server in a web browser and interact with the site. What can I do to go to the site on a browser and interact with the server that is running on the remote Linux machine? I was looking at guides for VNC and port forwarding but one thing that kept tripping me up was the fact that when it came time to do local port forwarding, I kept getting this error:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 5900
Could not request local forwarding.
```

when doing something like this:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:8000 <linux_ip>
```

where `<linux_ip>` is the IP address of the remote Linux machine. I'm having a hard time understanding how to properly do local port forwarding, and it seems like I'm not getting the port forwarding command right. The end goal here is to be able to access the site either on my own local web browser or through VNC to be able to graphically use the remote Linux machine. So how would I be able to do either one of those things?

Comment: You should check if something is already listening on port 5900 on your Mac.

Comment: How tremendously silly of me, I just assumed that there was something else going on other than that port simply being used already because both 5900 and 5901 gave me the same error. Just going to something other than those two, i.e. 5903, worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Douglas pointed out, port 5900 on my Mac was probably already being used. In my silliness I had thought that there was something else going on, since the same thing happened when I tried 5901 before. I didn't even consider the possibility that both were just being used. Going to an actually unused port like 5903 worked just fine.